# How to alert once a certain range is selected from slider when submitted?

Tags: javascript, css, slider

There is a slider range from 1 to 10 and if the user puts in on ranges 8 to 10, there should be an alertbox concerning those ranges when they clicked on the submit button. I've tried it but no luck. Here are my codes

Javascript

```
function showValue1(newValue)
{
  document.getElementById("range1").innerHTML=newValue;
}


$('submit1').submit(function () {
    if (newValue > 8 && newValue <10) {
        alert('TEST');
        return false;
    }
});
```

HTML

```
<div id="assess">
<div class="container">
<span id="range1">0</span>
<p class="mild">No pain</p>
<input name="pain" id="s1" type="range" min="0" max="10" value="0" step="1" oninput="showValue1(this.value)" />
<p class="extreme"><span class="adjust">Worst possible pain</span></p>
</div>    
<input id="submit1"type="submit" name="submit"value="Submit"></input></p>
```

Comment: a number can't be at the same time `< 8` and `> 10`, Check your `if` condition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code of html and js:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="assess">
        <div class="container">
            <span id="range1">0</span>
            <p class="mild">No pain</p>
            <input name="pain" id="s1" type="range" min="0" max="10" value="0" step="1" onchange="showValue1(this.value)" />
            <p class="extreme">
                <span class="adjust">Worst possible pain</span>
            </p>
        </div>
        <input id="submit1" type="submit" value="Submit"></input>
    </div>
</body>
```

I called JavaScript file js.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#submit1').click(function(){
        if($("#s1").val() >= 8 && $("#s1").val() <= 10)
            alert("TEST");
    });
});

function showValue1(newValue)
{
    document.getElementById("range1").innerHTML=newValue;
}
```

Comment: Opps I've changed it already. I'm still not able to change it

Comment: With your code I'm getting error: Uncaught ReferenceError: showValue1 is not defined. Let me see if I can modify this code to work

Answer (score 0):

You have not defined newValue and have used .submit(). You can use click event instead.Also for referencing the submit button make use of #.

Note: Because of the range that you have selected, it will alert true only for '9'

Here is the code that works for me:

```
$('#submit1').on('click',function () {
var newValue=$('#s1').val();//Extract the value of the slider and then use it for comparison
    if (newValue > 8 && newValue <10) {
        alert('TEST');
        return false;
    }
});
```